# How can we exclude certain words or tags from our search results on SoundCloud?

Tags: soundcloud

On SoundCloud, using `""` and `-` to filter my search results does nothing and gives me pages full of my excluded search terms.

Is there anything I can do to better control my search results? I'll search SoundCloud using a different site if that's what it takes.

Answer (score 1):

Relatively recently (30 May 2017) [gridsleep](https://soundcloudcommunity.com/desktop-230066/search-exclusion-7360936) wrote an information request cum minor rant:

> Does the search utility have any metatools? I need search exclusion, as in I want to search for "korg 707" for example and exclude all references to "tr-707" because I don't want to have to wade through tons of Roland TR-707 tracks, I only want Korg 707 tracks. I have tried negative sign, parentheses, negative parentheses, quotes. Nothing seems to work. Negating "tr" (-tr) actually only brings up references to "tr" so that's no good. Is SoundCloud's search utility really as stupid as it appears to be? It's 2017. UNIX had proper search tools in 1970.

From the deafening silence there since, I fear your answer is "You can't".